# CSS Transform-Origin Center Overflow Scroll Not Full Width

Tags: css, css-transforms

I've searched and can't find a solution or even ideas on this.

We have a child element inside a scrollable parent.  We transform the child to scale larger.  When the `transform-origin` is top left the `overflow: scroll` works correctly and you can scroll the entire thing.  When the `transform-origin` is center top it scales but the `overflow: scroll` only starts from the mid-point and there's no way to scroll to the first half of the child.

Here's a simple example showing how it works:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.001px;
}
.scale {
  border-radius: 0.001px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffff88;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: center top;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.scale--2{
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.scale {
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scale">First text - I'm scaling center top</div>
</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scale scale--2">First text - I'm scaling top left</div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts or hacks at this point would be awesome.

Comment: I believe that what you want, in other words,  is that there is a scrollbar appearing that is not at the left-most position.   This is not possible only with CSS, you will need JS

Comment: exactly. CSS cannot *move-scrollbar-where-desired*

Comment: Seems weird that it can detect how much to scroll to the right but not to the left.

Comment: @Fernker it's not weird. It's a overflow-scroll parent making space to accommodate it's child. painting a UI scrollbar is done therefore by the browser, but CSS cannot now do: "OK, now please move the scrollbar to the middle." What the browser provides is an API or actually methods you can access and control using JS to position the scrollbar.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan but if you inspect the child element the browser knows how wide it actually is and that the left side overflows the parent.

Comment: @Fernker I repeat. Knowing how wide an element is (in JS it's the `scrollWidth` property) is not the same as *now-please-move-the-scrollbar* (done using JS `scrollTo`, `scrollLeft`, `scrollTop` etc...) - Again: "paint a scrollbar depending on child size" is an obvoius result of a large child inside an overflow-scroll parent. Moving the scrollbar "automagically" is another (JavaScript) story.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm not really talking about now-please-move-the-scrollbar.  I'm really talking about how if you origin `center` the browser sees the element as half the width of what the browser says it is and treats it as when you transform `top left`.  

Transform `top left` overflows the parent only to the right.  Transform `center` overflows to the right and left.  Both should produce an equal scrollable area.

Comment: Also - I don't know why you're not doing `.wrapper:hover>.scale{scale}` (so that actually you can reach that scrollbar while the child is scaled...)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan mind providing a working example?

Comment: @Fernker using JS? sure!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry this has nothing to do with actually reaching the scrollbar, I can see how I misled you on that.  I've updated the question and removed the hover component.  So now you can scroll and hopefully see the difference.  On the top one you can't see the first words or get to them.

Comment: @Fernker in the meantime you can explore this example: https://jsfiddle.net/8vdf0kup/ - do you get the catch? Transform has nothing to do with your issue - hope you understand now. It's just how it works.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 `transform` has **[nothing to do with your issue](https://jsfiddle.net/8vdf0kup/1/)** ← you can replicate the same by using a simple `left: -100px;` on a standard (wider) child element.

1. (depending on text-direction) If you offset left an element out of a parent boundary - the browser will not paint for you the scrollbars - such element will simply be *eaten* by the overflow-scroll parent edge.
2. In the case the child is wider - the browser will paint UI scrollbars
3. But if you move that wide child to negative left... read again point 1.

the case can be expressed as `scrollWidth = childWidth - eatenLeftPortion`

**Therefore**

- Browser paints the UI scrollbars
- CSS **cannot** move scrollbars.
- The browser **will not** paint scrollbars if an element is pushed negative top or left (in text-direction ltr; right for rtl)

**solution**

- scale your element using `transform-origin: top left;` (your second example)
- (now the scrollbar is in it's full scrollable state since there's no left-eaten portions)
- using **JavaScript** animate or move `scrollLeft` by `(parentScrollWidth -
  parentWidth) / 2`

```js
var parent   = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
parent.scrollLeft = (parent.scrollWidth - parent.clientWidth) / 2 ;
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}


.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.scale {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffff88;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scale">I'm scaling center top</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For centering a child element within a parent div with parent scrollbars reflecting centered position of child element, I use the following code handled by a range input:

```
var scaleValue = $('#mySliderRange').val();

// Handles child scaling
child.css({'width':scaleValue+'%','height':scaleValue+'%'});

// Keeps child in vertical middle position
parent.scrollTop((child.height() - parent.height())/2);

// Keeps child in horizontal middle position
parent.scrollLeft((child.width() - parent.width())/2);
```

The above setup is a substitution to the issue of unreliable parent scrollbar positioning when dealing with CSS3 centered scaling. Hope this helps.